# Should the welcome message be blank in my inbox tab?

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox, network-profile, sign-up

When I signed up I received a welcome message:

[image: Welcome message]

Is that message supposed to be blank if I look at my *network profile*'s inbox tab?

It has a date, the site logo, "welcome", and a desolate empty wasteland with nary a message body:

[image: Welcome message without message body]